# FFmpeg: Error when trying to use encoding options copied from Mediainfo

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I want to encode different MKVs I have and I want to use the settings which I got from an existing encode via mediainfo:

Writing library: x265
Encoding Settings:

```
cpuid=1111039 / frame-threads=4 / numa-pools=24 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=1920x1080 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=0 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=3 / no-allow-non-conformance / no-repeat-headers / annexb / no-aud / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / no-temporal-layers / open-gop / min-keyint=25 / keyint=250 / gop-lookahead=0 / bframes=4 / b-adapt=2 / b-pyramid / bframe-bias=0 / rc-lookahead=20 / lookahead-slices=6 / scenecut=40 / radl=0 / no-splice / no-intra-refresh / ctu=64 / min-cu-size=8 / no-rect / no-amp / max-tu-size=32 / tu-inter-depth=1 / tu-intra-depth=1 / limit-tu=0 / rdoq-level=0 / dynamic-rd=0.00 / no-ssim-rd / signhide / no-tskip / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / no-constrained-intra / no-strong-intra-smoothing / max-merge=3 / limit-refs=1 / no-limit-modes / me=1 / subme=2 / merange=57 / temporal-mvp / no-hme / no-weightp / no-weightb / no-analyze-src-pics / no-deblock / no-sao / no-sao-non-deblock / rd=3 / selective-sao=0 / early-skip / rskip / no-fast-intra / no-tskip-fast / no-cu-lossless / no-b-intra / no-splitrd-skip / rdpenalty=0 / psy-rd=2.00 / psy-rdoq=0.00 / no-rd-refine / no-lossless / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=0 / rc=crf / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / stats-write=0 / stats-read=0 / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=2 / aq-strength=1.00 / cutree / zone-count=0 / no-strict-cbr / qg-size=32 / no-rc-grain / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-const-vbv / sar=1 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=0 / colorprim=1 / transfer=1 / colormatrix=1 / chromaloc=0 / display-window=0 / cll=0,0 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=255 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / no-opt-qp-pps / no-opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / scenecut-bias=0.05 / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / no-aq-motion / no-hdr / no-hdr-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / no-idr-recovery-sei / analysis-reuse-level=5 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=1 / refine-ctu-distortion=0 / no-limit-sao / ctu-info=0 / no-lowpass-dct / refine-analysis-type=0 / copy-pic=1 / max-ausize-factor=1.0 / no-dynamic-refine / no-single-sei / no-hevc-aq / no-svt / no-field / qp-adaptation-range=1.00
```

ffmpeg is just returning a lot of

```
Error parsing option
```

errors and I am not sure what to do?

What I read from other posts is that it has to do something with presets? But I do not really understand how to know what settings to use and which not.

Could someone help me to get the correct ffmpeg command to have same encoding settings as from mediainfo?

Answer (score 0):

Most of this can be done with `-preset` and `-tune` with some additional options manually set. According to [x265 Documentation - Preset Options](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/presets.html) it appears the *medium* preset was used, which is the default preset.

So your command could look like:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset medium -tune fastdecode -x265-params strong-intra-smoothing=0:colorprim=1:transfer=1:colormatrix=1 output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for the command it is almost identical now when I use the command from you above then it shows in mediainfo aq-mode=2 while in original it is aq-mode=1 what does that mean ? Also when using your command in mediainfo this is shown: no-frame-dup but in original not.

Comment: @VideoEncodeAmateur I was matching the parameters in your question which shows `aq-mode=2`. As for what it means refer to the [x265 documentation](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/cli.html). If you want to change it then add it to the `-x265-params` string. `aq-mode=1`. The x265 you are using for your new videos must be newer than the one used to make the old videos, so it has `frame-dup` option and the old doesn't. It is disabled by default, so you can ignore it.